# what is the actual meaning of "software testing"?

Tags: testing, performance-testing, manual-testing

testing means to check the software or application is error less?
to check that software or product functionality is proper as per client requirement

testing can improve quality, reliability, performance in product.

Comment: Have you answered your question or wanted to ask a question?

Comment: Software testing a process of finding or identifying defects in the software is called software testing. It is verifying the functionality ('behavior') of the application against requirements specification. It is the execution of the software with the intention of the finding the defects. It is checking whether software works according to the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Software testing has evolved in a number of ways over the years; from activity that was completed by developers during the software build; to dedicated test factories that validate and verify software deliveries, to approaches that write tests as specifications before the code is written (and more in between).

Many view software testing as verifying the requirements of the software have been delivered and validating they have been delivered in the right way. This type of software testing lends itself well to automated testing approaches where a boolean outcome of the test is achievable. As such, the approach to this testing typically uses a Triple A (Arrange, Act, Assert) model, whether at Unit, Integration, Acceptance or GUI test levels.

However, opponents to this approach reject the term 'testing' in favour or 'automated checking', and believe software 'testing' is the process of defining risk, designing experiments to expose the manifestations of those risk through understanding a better understanding of the software context. purpose, user communities and goals. These attributes can be difficult to describe in boolean terms, and therefore, (as described by [James Bach](https://www.satisfice.com)), software testing can be is seen as a learning opportunity to make informed choices about the software being developed.

A strong approach to software testing would consider both approaches and select the most relevant aspects from each.